# woocommerce_order_status_completed hook: force email AFTER action (instead of before)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I have written an action that attaches to woocommerce_order_status_completed, and it works fine, adding a bit of meta data to the order. But the email that goes out after order completed seems to go BEFORE this runs, and therefore does not send the meta data in question (it will send it if I rerun the completed order again, but that is because this data is now already in the DB). So what I am looking for is either:

- a hook that runs JUST before the completed email sends, OR
- a way to have the completed email send AFTER woocommerce_order_status_completed hook

Any ideas or pointers? I looked through the Woocommerce API reference but can't find anything that seems to suit.

**UPDATE:** found an earlier hook and tried hooking it into

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification','mysite_woocommerce_order_status_completed',5,1 );
```

which should run sooner, but STILL the email goes out first (before the meta data is in the DB and can be read. If I "recomplete" the order (putting it back into processing status and then completed again), it will send the meta data (again, this is because it is now in the db)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much hair pulling, I have come up with a workaround which seems kind of ugly, but hopefully it will help someone else out.

1. I verified that my hook WAS correctly running before the main email one. (using `add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification','mysite_woocommerce_order_status_completed',5,1 );`
   )
2. I verified that my meta data WAS correctly inserted into the db BEFORE the email went out

Unfortunately, it still refused to grab my meta data on first send. So I did the following:

I copied the woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-items.php template into my theme and made the following change:

```
// Variation
if ( ! empty( $item_meta->meta ) ) {
echo '<br/><small>' . nl2br( $item_meta->display( true, true, '_', "\n" ) ) . '</small>';

  // following 5 lines are MY extra code (checking for my meta field 'signup_code')
  if (!array_key_exists('signup_code',$item_meta->meta)) {
  $suc = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'signup_code' );
  if ($suc) {
  echo '<br/><small>signup_code: ' . $suc . '</small>';
  }}
}
```

It will check for a dupe in the meta array and not output if it already exists. It needs to do this to prevent it showing twice (which it would otherwise do on second send). I can't believe this is all necessary, but I can't find any other pointers anywhere that can address this.

**UPDATE:**
This was apparently caused by a woo internal caching problem. I had a lengthy discussion with one of the woo devs here:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/hook-an-action-before-transactional-woocommerce-emails-are-triggeredsent-out/page/2?replies=40#post-8379725

And the upshot is, it will be fixed in a future version, but you can see the changes here:

https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/commit/3db3f3796eb28fb79983f605a5a70d61ca114c6d